# Extract URL value and name for import with PHP?

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a web page with this type of list, about 500 items long:

```
<br><a href="urlvalue" >URL Name 1</a> text</br>
<br><a href="urlvalue" >URL with a longer url</a>text</br>
<br><a href="urlvalue" >URL Name3 and this one too?</a> text</br>
```

I want to import the data on this page to excel. So, I want to convert the data here to something like this:

```
URL value  | URL Name | Text
```

I'd actually settle for:

```
URL value | URL Name
```

I am using this:

I have used the simple-html-dom

```
<?php
require ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('Etext_alt2.html');


foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
    echo $element->href .'<br>'; 
?>
```

this gives me a nice listing of the URL values.

It seems like I should be able to access the other attributes, but nothing works.

Am I using the wrong thing? What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Just an FYI, you're using `<br>` wrong. There is no such thing as a `<br></br>` pair.

Comment: Have you tried using DOMDocument? Assuming your HTML isn't too terrible, it should be able to give you all of the items in your list.

Comment: Shauna- yes, not my code, but you're right.

Answer (score -1):

Working example for your task without parsing HTML:

```
$html = '<br><a href="urlvalue" >URL Name 1</a> text</br>
<br><a href="urlvalue" >URL with a longer url</a>text</br>
<br><a href="urlvalue" >URL Name3 and this one too?</a> text</br>';

preg_match_all('#<br><a href="(.*)" >(.*)</a>(.*)</br>#', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $row) {
    echo "{$row['1']} | {$row['2']} | {$row['3']}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```